# ¿Como rotar una imagen convertida en arreglo de bytes en C#?

Tags: c#, imagen, xamarin.forms

Estoy usando Xamarin.Forms para tomar una foto la cual la tomo vertical y tengo una foto más o menos así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta foto la combierto a arreglo de bytes y la guardo en una base de datos SQL Server, pero cuando la muestro esta se rota así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto sólo pasa con dispositivos iOS, con dispositivos Android mi imagen sale como la tomo.

Como puedo rotar el arreglo de bytes[], 90° en sentido del reloj?

para que mi imagen se inserte de forma Vertical y NO Horizontal?

Comment: No soy experto en Xamarin pero..estás seguro de que es la imagen la que esta rotada? No será el contenedor? No puedes si no es asi, rotar el contenedor en lugar de la imagen que es mas complejo?

Comment: Uso un contenedor de DevExpress, y cuando tomo la foto con Android esta se muestra como fue tomada, pero cuando la foto fue tomada con iOS esta se rota, así que quiero insertar el arreglo de bytes con la foto ya rotada